# Access Google Maps from outside

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have some javascript code, that draws a v3 GoogleMap.

I want to access the map object from outside (another js file).

Is there a possibility without creating an additional global variable to reference to the map ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate JS files are loaded and executed in the same scope, so there shouldn't be any functional difference whether you use one or multiple JS files.

Providing you control both scripts, you could pass in a reference to the map from script a to a callback function in script b:

from a.js:
`onMapCreated(myMap); // myMap is a reference to the created map`

from b.js:
    `function onMapCreated(map) {
        // do something with map
    }`

Obviously 'namespacing' your functions would be a good idea.

Comment: Mind you, scopes can be a bit vague due to the setup. An onLoad function for example can't be referenced within an object in another file.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the js that initializes the map object first in your page than any other js files that you include have access to this object if that is what you are asking