# How can I reference a google map in another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How can I reference a google map in another script? On my WordPress page, I load javascript (a) that builds my map, and jQuery script (b). I need to figure out some way passing a reference to the map to script (b). The problem is that the map is created inside a function in script (a).

In script (a), I've got:

```
function map_maker_js( args ) {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById( args['id'] ), myOptions);

//code for building map continues
}
```

In script (b):

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

//say I need the map's bounds
//how can I access map, in order for this to work: 
map.getBounds();

}
```

I saw this stackoverflow [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615052/access-google-maps-from-outside), but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stick it in the global namespace.

```
function map_maker_js( args ) {
     window.map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById( args['id'] ), myOptions);

     //code for building map continues
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    window.map.getBounds();
}
```

but make sure `map_maker_js` finishes running first.

Comment: Thank you for your message. How do I make sure that the map_maker_js finishes running first? At the moment, the jQuery is loading at the same time. Any suggestions? Thank you.